# Realtime analytics show page view gain and drop every other minute

Tags: centos, analytics

I have a server running Centos and Nginx and am noticing this in Analytics

[image]

The server keeps gaining to around 800-1000 page views per minute and then everytime it will drop to around 4-500 the following minute.

What is causing this?

Comment: This somehow looks like an artifact of badly selected measurement intervals. Analyze your log files to verify this is really happening.

Comment: Check your referring site report, and your logs.

Comment: @Sven It's a screenshot from Google Analytics' real-time stats view. You don't get to pick a measurement interval there.

Comment: It seems to only happen when there are more then 1000 people on a particular page. Maybe a server limit?